# How do I set up two digital TV tuners in windows media center?

Tags: windows-7, tv, windows-media-center, hdtv, tuner-card

I've been using Windows Media Center on Windows Home Premium for some time now with a single [PCTV nanostick T2](http://www.pctvsystems.com/Products/ProductsEuropeAsia/DVBTT2products/PCTVnanoStickT2/tabid/248/language/en-GB/Default.aspx) and it works great to receive both standard and high def shows.

I've just bought another stick so I can watch and record simultaneously but I'm struggling to get it working.

If I let Windows detect my tuners it takes an age and eventually only finds the DVB-T part of the tuners and consequently only the SD channels.

If I tell Windows to use the two DVB-T tuners and two ClearQAM parts of the tuners it doesn't find any channels at all.

What am I doing wrong? Microsoft say [it should support two tuners](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/what-should-i-know-before-adding-tv-tuners-to-use-with-windows-media-center) so what gives?

Comment: Check `Device Manager` for status that both tuners are properly recognized and installed.

Comment: I have and they are..

Comment: Just going back to one tuner (the new one), when I ask the tuner to detect TV signals, it finds `Digital Antenna (DVB-T)` and that other tuners are available but no TV signals were detected for 'PCTV 80e/290e/460e BDA 2875 TVTuner C`. Could that be it?